# Mixing high and low DPI screens

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, hdpi

I have a Lenovo X1 Carbon 7th Gen (3840x2160) and I am using it in conjunction with two older DELL monitors (1920x1280). Running Ubuntu Mate 19.10.

Most of the major elements I interact with (browsers, media players, e-mail clients, etc.) are already behaving nicely in this mixed environment (I am pretty impressed with what the Mate guys have done), but there are some outliers that trouble me.

For example, the QT based clipboard manager CopyQ. If I simply execute it, it looks gigantic on the older monitors and normal on the laptop. Since I do not know which screen the widget will pop up on, I cannot globally set `QT_SCALE_FACTOR`.

Since these are indeed outliers, I do not want to solve this using `xrandr`, not to mention the toll it takes on the display quality.

What other option do I have?